# Multiple Wordpress Blogs on one host, using 1 WordPress installation, using multiple templates

Tags: multisite

Hay, I was wondering if this is possible. I have a company called dotty. The domain for this company is dotty.com. However, my company has many subcompanies (company_1, company_2). Is it possible using WordPress to manage all these subcompanies within one WordPress installation? Each company needs to have it's own template, and the URL's will end up something like this

```
dotty.com
dotty.com/company_1
dotty.com/company_2
```

and i can manage them all from

```
dotty.com/wp-admin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a WordPress Network. This is one installation with unlimited numbers of blogs, all controlled, to a point, by the central dashboard. See [Create A Network - WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: Does WordPress Network allow me to have each site skinned by a different template?

Comment: Yep each site can be themed on it own and managed on its on.